# Bitstamp and deposit address

Tags: address, bitstamp

I have a Bitstamp account and when I try to use the API for bitcoin deposit I discover that there is a unique address for my bitcoin deposit. It is safe in term of address reuse consideration ? Here for instance (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Address_reuse) it's mentioned to not use the same address for several transactions

Comment: Is it the same even after depositing to that address? Or you get the same one until you use it for payment once? If so, which version of API do you use?

Comment: Actually I have not yet deposit any BTC on it ; you believe that once I would have done it the address will be changed for further deposit ?

Comment: exactly, I guess so. Have you tested it?

Comment: Not yet I am still under software development process

Comment: Sure, Let me know once you tested

Comment: It is always the same unfortunatly

Comment: Is the Wallet Name the same as the bitcoin deposit address?